# how to add timthumb in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working in gallery website..But I got problem about Image displaying..
I know about timthumb and worked well in php demo..but when I enqueue ***timthumb*** in wordpress with help of function.php i got error... :(

**function.php**

```
define('tt_path',get_template_directory().'/timthumb/');
require_once(tt_path.'timthumb.php');
```

ERROR :

[image]

Comment: It's no longer maintained due to a widely-exploited vulnerability, FYI

Comment: is there any alternative?same functionality as timthumb...

Comment: Lots. Here's one http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/moving-away-from-timthumb-to-bfithumb--wp-33743

Comment: hey drakes, I used bfi thumn but it does not resize my image ...i also used parameter 'crop'...

Comment: well, BFITHUMB NOT RESIZE MY IMAGE AND SET BACKGROUND WHITE AND ALSO NOT CROPPING CENTER ,TOP,BOTTOM OPTIONs,ALSO AFTER RESIZE not put my image center like ****TIMTHUMB*****

Comment: Your caps lock key is stuck

Comment: well,Bfithumb not working well for me...and it has not options that timthumb has....it there any other alternatives exclude the bfi thumb..?

Comment: I googled around about your problem. Please give this a read and see if it helps you with TimThumb: https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/issues/detail?id=427 (Yes, TimThumb was the plugin almost everyone used, but it's gone. We have to adapt. So far there isn't a drop-in alternative, but BFIThumb is closest: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/moving-away-from-timthumb-to-bfithumb--wp-33743)